# node-forge package error with RSA enc/dec

Tags: node.js, encryption, meteor, cryptography, rsa

I'm using node-forge npm on my meteor.js web app. I'm trying to do RSA encryption on some plain text according to this example: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa

The problem arrives when I want to decrypt the ciphertext where I want to get back the plaintext where it says the encryption block is invalid.

Following the example, I have to encrypt the bytes from the string so all that is done, but I don't understand why it fails on decryption? Any guesses?

```
rsaEncrypt:function(pubPem,privPem,plainText){

console.log(plainText);

var str = plainText;
var bytes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
  bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
}

console.log("BAJTOVI:");
console.log(bytes);

var publicKey = pki.publicKeyFromPem(pubPem);
console.log(publicKey);

var encrypted = publicKey.encrypt(bytes);
console.log("Encryption: ");
console.log(encrypted);

var privateKey = pki.privateKeyFromPem(privPem);
var decrypted = privateKey.decrypt(encrypted);

console.log("Decryption: ");
console.log(decrypted);

function bin2String(decrypted) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < decrypted.length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(decrypted[i], 2));
  }
  return result;
}
console.log("OPET TEXT:");
console.log(result);

return decryted;

},
```

The problem i get from the server:

```
Exception while invoking method 'rsaEncrypt' Error: Encryption block is invalid.
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at Object._decodePkcs1_v1_5 [as decode] (/Users/mrcina/Meteor Projects/cryptonic/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/node-forge/js/rsa.js:1446:11)
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at Object.key.decrypt (/Users/mrcina/Meteor Projects/cryptonic/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/node-forge/js/rsa.js:1083:19)
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.rsaEncrypt (server/methods.js:49:32)
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1698:12)
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at livedata_server.js:708:19
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at livedata_server.js:706:40
I20151110-21:22:05.279(1)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20151110-21:22:05.280(1)?     at livedata_server.js:704:46
I20151110-21:22:05.280(1)?     at tryCallTwo (/Users/mrcina/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.1.1wnrf8h++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
```

THis line: **var decrypted = privateKey.decrypt(encrypted);**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forge doesn't use arrays of integers to represent bytes; it uses binary-encoded strings. Try simplifying your code to the following:

```
rsaEncrypt:function(pubPem,privPem,plainText){

  console.log(plainText);

  var publicKey = pki.publicKeyFromPem(pubPem);
  console.log(publicKey);

  var encrypted = publicKey.encrypt(forge.util.encodeUtf8(plainText));
  console.log("Encryption: ");
  console.log(encrypted);

  var privateKey = pki.privateKeyFromPem(privPem);
  var decrypted = forge.util.decodeUtf8(privateKey.decrypt(encrypted));

  console.log("Decryption: ");
  console.log(decrypted);

  return decrypted;
}
```